# Java Comparator sorting order with duplicate values

Tags: java

I am confused with this code and my main objective here is i would like to sort if the order.name's are same, other wise -1 or +1 is fine for me.

Expected out put result:

```
 "abc"   "abc"   "def"   "ghi"   "ijk"
```

but the program is doing something different. am i missing anything here.

```
`import java.util.*;
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        List<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>();

        list.add(new Order(10, "abc"));
        list.add(new Order(20, "def"));
        list.add(new Order(10, "abc"));
        list.add(new Order(40, "ghi"));
        list.add(new Order(50, "ijk"));

        Collections.sort(list, new CustComparator());

        System.out.println(" For Loop Results");
        for (Order object : list) {
            System.out.println(((Order) object).getName());
        }

    }

    static class CustComparator implements Comparator<Order> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
            if (o1.getName().equals(o2.getName())) {
                System.out.println(" This line of code is not executing ");
                return 0;
            } else {
                System.out.println(" This line of code is executing ");
                return -1;
            }

        }

    }

    static class Order {

        public Order() {
        }

        public Order(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private int id;
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Order other = (Order) obj;
            /*
             * if (id != other.id) return false;
             */
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}`
```

and the program out put is this:

```
This line of code is executing    
 This line of code is executing   
 This line of code is executing   
 This line of code is executing
```

For Loop Results

```
ijk  
ghi  
abc  
def  
abc
```

---

Thank you all and thanks for all your responses,

Finally i did this something like this, since i am looking for all "abc" should display first in the order. Here is my custom comparator.

```
static class CustComparator implements Comparator<Order> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {

        int old=getModuleIndex(o1.getName());
        int new1 = getModuleIndex(o2.getName());
        if (old == new1) {
            return 0;
        } else if(old > new1){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
    int getModuleIndex(String obj) {
        if(obj.equals("abc")) {
            return 1;               
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your implementation does not satisfy the contract for `Comparator`. It should not be a surprise that it behaves strangely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: Edit the `compare()` method

```
public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
    return o1.getName.compareTo(o2.getName);
}
```

**Note:** When comparing object, it is need to return 3 values: 0 if the argument string is equal to this string. a value less than 0 if this string is less than the string argument. and a value greater than 0 if this string is greater than the string argument.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your program does not work as expected is because your `compare` method violates the contract of `compare` as described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-)

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y

In your case `compare(x,y)` and `compare(y,x)` are always -1 if x != y which violates this contract. That is why the sorting does not work.

How to fix it? Well in your case it's pretty easy: Just implement the `compare` corectly

```
@Override
public int compare(Order o1, Order o1) {
  return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have explained the problem with your custom comparator.

I'd like to add the fact that you can achieve all you want without creating your own comparator class. In fact methods in the comparator interface even allow you to sort by multiple criteria.

For example, if you want to sort by name and then id (for items with the same name):

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Order::getName).thenComparing(Order::getId));
```

Comment: thank  you all and thanks for all your time. Finally i did this something like this, since i am looking for all "abc" should display first in the order.